# Is it possible to move the running pods from ReplicationController to a Deployment?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, replicaset

We are using RC to run our workload and want to migrate to Deployment. Is there a way to do that with out causing any impact to the running workload. I mean, can we move these running pods under Deployment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like, @matthew-l-daniel answered, the answer is yes. But I am more than 80% certain about it. Because I have tested it

Now whats the process we need to follow

Lets say I have a ReplicationController.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**Question:** can we move these running pods under Deployment?

Lets follow these step to see if we can.

**Step 1:** 
Delete this RC with `--cascade=false`. This will leave Pods.

**Step 2:**
Create ReplicaSet first, with same label as ReplicationController

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      ---
```

So, now these Pods are under ReplicaSet.

**Step 3:**
Create Deployment Now with same label.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      ----
```

And Deployment will find one ReplicaSet already exists and our job is done.

Now we can check increasing `replicas` to see if it works.

And It works.

**Which way It doesn't work**

After deleting ReplicationController, do not create Deployment directly. This will **not work**. Because, Deployment will find no ReplicaSet, and will create new one with additional label which will not match with your existing Pods

Comment: Thats right, I was trying to create the deployment after deleting RC and it was failing. Now i understand the requirement of the intermediate step to create the ReplicaSet

Answer (score 2):

I'm about 80% certain the answer is yes, since they both use Pod selectors to determine whether new instances should be created. The key trick is to use the `--cascade=false` (the default is `true`) in `kubectl delete`, whose help even speaks to your very question:

> --cascade=true: If true, cascade the deletion of the resources managed by this resource (e.g. Pods created by a ReplicationController).  Default true.

By deleting the `ReplicationController` but **not** its subordinate Pods, they will continue to just hang out (although be careful, if a reboot or other hazard kills one or all of them, no one is there to rescue them). Creating the Deployment with the same selector criteria and a `replicas` count equal to the number of currently running Pods should cause a "no action" situation.

I regret that I don't have my cluster in front of me to test it, but I would think a small `nginx` RC with replicas=3 should be a simple enough test to prove that it behaves as you wish.